# Posting content to Facebook API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post to Facebook API using Javascript.  It  works well when the content is hard coded in Javascript, but when I gather the content from a textbox entered by user.  It throw a Same-origin policy error:

This is where I do the posting.

```
        FB.api('/1494363804210145/feed', 'post', postData, 
        function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            $("#status").val("Your Message as been posted!");
        });
```

If postData is hardset, it works:

```
        var postData = { 
            message      : "TEST",
            name         : "TEST",
            from         : 'pageid',
            access_token : pageAccessToken,
            description  : "TEST"
        };
```

If postData is dynamic, it does not work:

```
        var postData = { 
            message      : $("#postMessage"),
            link         : $("#postLink"),
            picture      : $("#postImage"),
            name         : $("#postTitle"),
            from         : 'pageid',
            access_token : pageAccessToken,
            description  : $("#postDesc")
        };
```

I am not using IFrame of any kind.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The issue with your code is you are not retrieving value or text from those selectors, you are just assigning object keys value as `jQuery selector` which will return `object`. Either you call the method `val()` if those are form elements or `html() / text()` if you want content from those elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append `.val()`. Right now you are trying to post the `jQuery object`.

```
var postData = { 
    message      : $("#postMessage").val(),
    link         : $("#postLink").val(),
    picture      : $("#postImage").val(),
    name         : $("#postTitle").val(),
    from         : 'pageid',
    access_token : pageAccessToken,
    description  : $("#postDesc").val()
};
```